# How set smtp credential in .net

Tags: c#, email, smtp, email-validation

I have a contact us page that user fill contents and contents send to email like *info@mywebsitename.com*. in .net we define credential for smtp :

```
        var body = c.Subject.ToString() + " from: " + c.Name + " " + c.Email + "\n\n" + c.Body;
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage(c.Email, "info@mysitename.com", c.Subject.ToString(), body);
        var mailAddr = new MailAddress(c.Email);
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Host = "mail.mysitename.com";
        **smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@mysitename.com", "Test123");**
        smtpClient.send();
```

any works well.

but if User change password of *info@mywebsitename.com*, this credential is not valid. it's a human right that user have access to password and change it! so how have valid credential for ever that customers can send email to info and site owner can reply to them and can change password.

I know can set in web.config. Is there way for dynamically set password.

Comment: If the password changes then your code needs to change, or put the password in a config file so you don't need to recompile.

Comment: tnx, so you mean there's no way to set pass dynamically.

Comment: When you set up SMTP in an application, it's normal to use an account that isn't used by a "real" person and is only there for the purposes of your application sending email. That way you don't need to change the password.

Answer (score 1):

you want something like this.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="email@yourdomain.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network defaultCredentials="false" host="yourdomain" password="password" userName="username"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the property 'UseDefaultCredentials' of 'SmtpClient' to false. Depending on your email server you will eventually have to set 'EnableSsl' to true. Here is a sample of code which I have used to successfully connect to Gmail:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.googlemail.com");
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myaccountname@gmail.com", "mypassword");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
```